# Will faced insulation behind poly sheeting trap moisture?

Tags: walls, bathtub, exterior

I insulated an exterior wall in my shower. I had some faced insulation to use up so put it in the wall with the paper to the outside, no staples or tape. I have 6 mil plastic for interior vapor barrier. Will the facing trap too much moisture? There’s no housewrap on the exterior with gaps in the sheeting and vinyl siding. I’m in cold weather state of Wisconsin.

Answer (score -1):

We don't use plastic sheeting for vapor barrier (on warm side of wall) anymore. We've learned that moisture (vapor) will get past the plastic sheeting (I.e.: around outlets, switches, vents, etc.) and then not be able to "move" back out of the wall. Then, that creates rot.

Also, the paper vapor barrier needs to be moved to the warm side of the wall.

Comment: You might qualify who "we" are. I'm in Minnesota, which is nearly identical in climate to Wisconsin, and every home is sealed up tightly with poly sheeting and caulk here (electrical boxes are flanged with integrated foam seals). Your post seems to indicate a consensus on the subject that simply doesn't apply in my region.